# dotConnect and calling procedure with parameters problem

Tags: c#, dotconnect

This is my code for calling procedure:

```
cmd.CommandText = "x.PROCEDURENAME";

cmd.Parameters["V_IID_DOKUMENT_PO"].Value = "1";
cmd.Parameters["x"].Value = x.Text;
cmd.Parameters["x"].Value = x.Text;
cmd.Parameters["x"].Value = x.Text;
cmd.Parameters["x"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(x.Text);
cmd.Parameters["x"].Value = x.Text;
cmd.Parameters["x"].Value = x.Text;
cmd.Parameters["x"].Value = x.Text;
cmd.Parameters["x"].Value = x.Text;
cmd.Parameters["x"].Value = "1";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but i get

> A parameter with name 'V_IID_DOKUMENT_PO' is not contained by this
>   Parameters collection.

if i check in DB

```
PROCEDURE PROCEDURENAME
 (V_IID_DOKUMENT_PO IN NUMBER
  ...
```

what i am doing wrong?

If i use:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("V_IID_DOKUMENT_PO", OracleDbType.Number, 1);
```

i get invalid sql statement

Comment: Do you get error only for that parameter or for the rest as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use,

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("V_IID_DOKUMENT_PO", OracleDbType.Number).Value=1;
```

Comment: I would argue against using this - what happens is that ADO.NET must now **guess** what type that parameters is. Most of the time, that guess is pretty good - but it's still a guess and it can go wrong (esp. if you pass `DbNull.Value` as value.... how should ADO.NET know **what** actual type this parameter will be???). I would **always** use the `Parameters.Add(<name>, DbType.XXXXX)` to **clearly** define what your parameter types are

Answer (score 2):

Did you specify that this is a stored procedure you're calling??

E.g. do you have this line somewehre (your sample code posted seems incomplete):

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: no i did not have this. I couldn't find this in dotConnect C# example. Thx